# ORACLE PL/SQL: ORDER BY CASE Performance

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I currently have a server side paging query as such:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT a.*, rownum rnum FROM (
        ( /* Insert Query Here */ ) ) a
      WHERE rownum <= ((page_number + 1) * page_size))
      WHERE rnum >= (((page_number  + 1) * page_size)) - (page_size - 1);
```

The problem, however, is trying to determine what the user is sorting on as this is tied to a gridview. Currently, I'm using:

```
ORDER BY 
        CASE sort_direction
          WHEN 'ASC' THEN
            CASE sort_column
              WHEN 'PRIMARY_KEY' THEN
                primary_key
              ELSE key
            END
        END    
        ASC,
        CASE sort_direction
          WHEN 'DESC' THEN
            CASE sort_column
              WHEN 'PRIMARY_KEY' THEN
                primary_key
              ELSE key
            END
        END    
        DESC
```

I'm using this on every query I stick into the server side paging scheme. The problem is that when I have a grid that has quite a few fields, the performance degrades substantially. Is there any other way to do this? Do I need to simply set less fields to allow paging?

Comment: Is 'Insert Query Here' a placeholder for *one specific* queries, or for *several* queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Dynamic SQL and build the ORDER BY at runtime. Oracle's SQL engine will see a simple ORDER BY.

Comment: This is what I'm attempting now, but I'm having trouble actually putting results into a ref_cursor.

Comment: What type of trouble? Error message? At compile time? Runtime? When I used dynamic sql to return a ref cursor I found it had to be a weak ref cursor.

Comment: Got it. I was missing sort values as for some reason they weren't passing. Dynamic SQL with a FIRST_ROWS hint made my query run in a tenth of a second. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the optimizer can't figure this out, and thus can't use indices. Check what EXPLAIN PLAN says.

Obvious solution is to have your app "evaluate" that case, and send a much simpler query. I think you'll find `ORDER BY primary_key ASC` to be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

If the primary_key and key are numbers then a descending query is the same as an ascending multiplied by -1.

```
order by direction * CASE sort_column
                       WHEN 'PRIMARY_KEY' THEN primary_key
                       ELSE key              END
```

In the above, direction is an integer. Pass in 1 or -1. This is a much simpler expression and should run faster.